# Why does including iostream give errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, iostream

I am writing a simple program down below in C++ using Visual Studio 2015 and when I `#include <iostream>` I get a bunch of errors like in the image below:
My code can be found below and in the image.

```
// FirstProject.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!";

    int pause;
    pause = 0;
    std::cin >> pause;

    return 0;
}
```

[Code and Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFwvi.png)

Comment: From the looks of that error list, your include-path contains no C++ standard library headers.

Comment: This will be an error inside the stdafx.h header file. Everything else about the code looks fine to me.

Comment: @Swemoph you're right I looked into it and found two errors when including files (#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>) 
// cannot open source files
but I am new to c++ so I do not understand why this occurs, any thoughts?

Comment: Remove `#include "stdafx.h"` from your FirstProject.cpp file. You cannot access the source of the files you mentioned - they are in the compiler.

Comment: @Swemoph this did not help me in terms of removing all those errors but thank you for taking time out of your day to help me

Comment: Try removing all the files that you aren't using from the project, so the `stdafx.cpp`, `stdafx.h` and `targetver.h`. It should then compile. If not just go ahead and create a new empty c++ console application

Comment: Errors should generally be included as *text* in the question. Not as image.

Comment: there are 450 errors

Comment: @Swemoph VS does not store library headers "in the compiler"; its header files are, unsurprisingly, actually files. Whether the installation in question here is properly configured to look in the standard folder that contains those files is another matter.

Comment: I was referring to the actual source files, not the header files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Errors came from Visual Studio 2015 not being able to properly locate the include files.

Comment: If this solved your problem, it only did so by masking some fatal misconfiguration of IntelliSense: that would be the real problem.

Comment: No it was an error with VS 2015 not being able to find it's include files